# Why can't the top demon control Liebe?

Tags: black-clover

My question is if the Demon Lord in the past can control the null magic demon Liebe when he was with Asta's mother.

Why can't he control him when he is fighting with Asta on they're Black Bull's Base while being inside the spade kingdom's top tier fighter?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly liebe didnt had any magic not even anti magic so he couldn't do anything. He got anti magic after lictha (Asta Mom) sealed him in the five leaf grimoire
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S5Ti.jpg)
he cursed the other devils until he got his anti magic (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtQXT.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4ipM.png)
I think since he has anti magic lucefero couldn't posses him.since he was canceling all magic around him
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA3KD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Liebe does not have the power of antimagic. He has no magic at all. Therefore he cannot be controlled by the Demon Lord.